# OpenLiteSpeed Changing http port from 8088 to 80 not working

Tags: unix, litespeed, openlitespeed

I am fresh to openlitespeed. I've succesfully installed the server and Wordpress above it.
Now I can reach my wordpress installation from http://x.x.x.x:8088
But
When I try to replace the HTTP port from 8088 to 80, I get a timeout.

May you please help?

I tried following the procedures in this tutorial
https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-configure-openlitespeed-server-on-fedora-31-along-with-mariadb/

Comment: what does it show if you run `netstat -lnp | grep litespeed` ?

Comment: `[opc@openlitespeed-vm ~]$ sudo netstat | grep litespeed
tcp        1      0 openlitespeed-vm.:47032 169.254.169.254:http    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1      0 openlitespeed-vm.:47028 169.254.169.254:http    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 openlitespeed-vm.:56770 169.254.169.254:http    ESTABLISHED
tcp       32      0 openlitespeed-vm.:47252 140.204.34.137:https    CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0     36 openlitespeed-vm.pu:ssh 188.161.41.234:60236    ESTABLISHED
`

Comment: One more thing to tell that might help: 
`sudo curl http://150.230.243.48:7080
sudo curl http://localhost:80
sudo curl http://127.0.0.1:80`

all these commands work fine, but : `sudo curl http://150.230.243.48:80 `lasts forever

Comment: it usually means firewall issue , try disable firewalld , see how it goes , if you are using provider like GCP, AWS , they also have a network-level firewall , might need to check that as well